# qsort a list of class objects

Tags: c++, list, class, qsort

I'm writing a sorting code to an existing library, so I cannot make changes in the data model 
I have the following

```
 class Point
 {

   //Some functions 
   public:
       float x, y, z;

  };

int less_than_key (const void *arg1, const void *arg2)
 {

      Point *r1 = (Point*) arg1;
      Point *r2 = (Point*) arg2;

      if(r1->z < r2->z )
        return -1;

     else if(r1->z > r2->z )
       return 1;
    else
       return 0;
}

int main()
{
   list<Point> myPoints; 

    Point p;
    p.x = 0;
    p.y = 0;
    p.z = 0;
    myPoints.push_back(p);

    p.x = 0;
    p.y = 0;
    p.z = 6;
    myPoints.push_back(p);

    p.x = 0;
    p.y = 0;
    p.z = 2;
    myPoints.push_back(p);

    for(int i=0; i<myPoints.size(); i++)
      cout<<" Point "<<p[i].x<<", "<<p[i].y<<", "<<p[i].z<<"\n";

    qsort(&myPoints, myPoints.size(), sizeof(Point), less_than_key);

    for(int i=0; i<myPoints.size(); i++)
      cout<<"Point "<<p[i].x<<", "<<p[i].y<<", "<<p[i].z<<"\n";
 }
```

I want to sort the objects depending on the z value.
The output I expect is the following

```
 Before sorting 
 Point 0, 0, 0
 Point 0, 0, 6
 Point 0, 0, 2

 After sorting 
 Point 0, 0, 0
 Point 0, 0, 2
 Point 0, 0, 6
```

When I run the following code, it crashes during the sorting call and I get the following error

```
  terminated with signal 11
```

I read in other solutions that I should pass the list as the following

```
   qsort(&myPoints[0], myPoints.size(), sizeof(Point), less_than_key);
```

But when I try to compile it I get the following

```
  no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::list<Point>' and 'int')
```

Comment: If you're using C++ why not use `std::sort`?

Comment: `qsort` requires the data to be contiguous anyway. Data in an `std::list` is not contiguous.

Comment: `qsort` also requires the data being sorted to be a `C` compatible type, i.e. a `POD` type.  If your `Point` class has user-defined constructors, destructors, etc., then you *cannot* use `qsort` to sort the items.  Basically, `std::is_pod<Point>::value` is false, then drop using `qsort` since the behavior will be undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use std::sort with lambda expresion, here is an example:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::list<Point> myPoints;

//adding points to list...

std::sort(myPoints.begin(), myPoints.end(), [](const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs)
{
   return lhs.z < rhs.z;
});

for(int i=0; i<myPoints.size(); i++)
  cout<<"Point "<<p[i].x<<", "<<p[i].y<<", "<<p[i].z<<"\n";
```

Code above will sort, and then print sorted list of points

Answer (score 0):

Stl list has its own sort function that accepts a compare function. You can write a compare function that takes two reference **Point** objects and pass it to **myPoints.sort(..)**

See [1]http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/

Answer (score 0):

`qsort` is old school C. It expects 4 parameters:

> **ptr**    -   pointer to the array to sort
>
> **count**  -   number of elements in the array
>
> **size**   -   size of each element in the array in bytes
>
> **comp**   -   comparison function which returns ​a negative integer value if the first argument is less than the second, 
>   a positive integer value if the first argument is greater than the second and zero if the arguments are equal.

[from `std::qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort)

What it has been given is

- pointer to a `list`
- number of elements in the array
- size of each element in the array in bytes
- Comparison function

It's the pointer to `list` that kills you. I suspect this is a `std::list`, but can't prove that. Whatever it is, it is a templated data structure and this makes things hairy. It is NOT an array and should not be used as an array.

`qsort` tried to use it as an array, and to quote Dune:

> They tried and failed?
>
> They tried and died.

Now for all we know, `list` could be a very [simple structure](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) that contains an array of `Point` that is perfectly positioned to line up with the beginning of the instance--the address of the contained array is the same as the address of the instantiated `list`--but the crash suggests otherwise.

And if `list` is a dynamic array (suggested by its usage) or linked list (suggested by the name and the usage), then a `list` instance doesn't even contain its data. It contains a pointer to the data. There is no array for `qsort` to use and it will quickly run through what little data is stored in `list`, out the other side and into the wild and wacky world of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). That said, The instance you passed a non-array into `qsort` you'd already hit Undefined Behaviour.

The solution is to use C++'s [built in `std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) if `list` has an iterator interface. if `list` is really `std::list` there may be performance advantages [in using `std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort). If neither is true and `list` is an unfortunately named custom class, you'll have to write your own sort routine (or do the smart thing and chuck the custom class in favour of a library container).